# Can I get the highest amount of a value in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, key, field

I want to display the user with the most posts. the posts are added by counting how many times their username is displayed in the database. How can I grab all the elements and check to see which value appears more then others?

So say my database looks like this:

```
id | username
1 | test
2 | test
3 | no test
```

"test" is shown the most, so how could I say

```
highest poster: "test"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query returns `username` and number of occurrences, sorted in reverse order, so the first record is the one with more occurrences:

```
select username, count(id) from tablename 
group by username
order by count(id) desc
```

UPDATE:
As pointed by *thedugas* and *Joe Phillips*, you can add a `limit 1` clause to this query to get only the record with the highest number of occurrences

Answer (score 1):

```
select username, count(id) as uc
from tableName
group by username
order by uc desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username
FROM mytable
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
LIMIT 1
```